# Head styles in emails?

Tags: css, email, html-email

I know to use media queries and anchor pseudo classes I need to place them in the head of an email rather than inlining the styles (impossible).

Does it make any difference with the plethora of email clients out there is the styles are written in the head like so:

```
<style>
    body {
        ....
    }
</style>
```

Or linked like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://example.com/mystyle.css">
```

Comment: Litmus statistics show 95% of email clients support CSS in the head now (even media queries). Yahoo app supports in body.

Comment: Syfer - not the question asked.

Comment: In simple terms what i meant was to use CSS in head. Linking works on a few email clients only. Wasnt that what you were after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best is for style to be written in the document and not linked. Linked resources are blocked by webmail clients like Outlook.com, Yahoo and Gmail

Use this guide for style support of email clients:
https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: SInce this answer is accepted just wanted to put it out there, the link is 3 years old and a few things have changes since then. Yahoo mail has started accepting CSS in body (it was not accepted then it was accepted again) and gmail now supports CSS but not all of it.

Answer (score 3):

Do not rely on external `(<link rel="stylesheet">)` or embedded style sheets (those contained within the `<style>` tag outside the `<body>` tag), these are the most important thing to avoid. **

> Many email services cut everything above the body tag and disable
>   external style sheets.

**It's best to use `<style>` tag inside `<body>`**

```
<body>
<style type="text/css">
  body {
     ....
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    ....
  }
</style> 
</body>
```

If you want more details you can refer to this ***[link](https://www.benchmarkemail.com/help-FAQ/answer/Using-CSS-in-HTML-emails)***, It was quite helpful for me, Cheers...